# How do I create a PKCS#7 or CMS SignedData in python?

Tags: signature, cms

There doesn't appear to be PKCS#7 or CMS support in pyCrypto. I'd appreciate a recommendation on a Python library wth CMS / PKCS#7 support. Ideally, there will be a call that will create return SignedData given a signer certificate, an RSA private key and a payload (File or byte array) to sign.

I've looked at pycrypto-PKCS7 and as best as I am able to tell it only verifys signatures.

Your help / insights are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Programming help is off topic here. If you run into an on-topic implementation problem when programming it, feel free to ask about those. (E.g. ambiguity in standards, avoidance of side-channel attacks, etc. could be on topic.)

Comment: FYI although envelope is a general concept, in PKCS#7/CMS/S/MIME context it specifically means (hybrid) *encryption*: `EnvelopedData` is encrypted, `SignedData` is signed, 
and `SignedAndEnvelopedData` (PKCS#7-only, dropped in CMS) is both. The SignedData 
options you might care about are (1) the data is *in* the SignedData or (2) the data is "external" and 
the signature is "detached"; this is used for, and also called, "clear-sign[ing]". Using standard terminology will 
make your question(s) clearer to the people most likely able to help you.

Comment: @Otus A programming difficulty (say, in using a library function correctly) rightly belongs in stackoverflow rather than here methinks. A standards / specification ambiguity or problem is best dealt with in / with the body that owns and maintains the standard e.g. IETF. My thinking is that the Cryptography group in StackExchange helps with difficulties in applying, building and analyzing cryptographic protocols, ciphers, methods.

Comment: @kbear, that's more or less correct, but some [tag:implementation] questions and many questions about [tag:standards] are on topic. It's a question of whether they are about the cryptography or not. Anyway, your question remains off topic.

Comment: @Otus, This does feel like a gray zone.  This question: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19575/using-c-sign-to-create-a-pkcs7-signature?rq=1 was deemed in scope.  The difference seems to be that there a user used a PKCS#11 library and expected to get a PKCS#7 result, eliciting some helpful answers on using the right (PKCS#7) library.  That is analogous to my using PKCS#1 in PyCryto and wondering how to get to PKCS#7, rather than just asking what library to use for PKCS#7.  How should I be looking at this so I know what is in and out of bounds?  Thanks.

Comment: @kbear, honestly, the bounds *are* gray. That question you linked looks like it asks how the two formats relate, which seems on topic. The answer and comments just ended up recommending some library as... sort of a side note. If library suggestions are the main thing you are after, I recommend [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) instead.